# K means Clustering using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, cluster-analysis

I have a very big data frame, I have to use specific 8 columns from the data frame where the values are either "strongly agree", "agree" or "disagree". Depending on these 8 columns, I need to create a new column which tell which cluster(1-8) the row belongs to (preferably by using K-means clustering).

Is this possible in PySpak?

PS: I am new to PySpark, Any help would be highly appreciated

```
column:1     Column:2    column:3   column:4    column:5 .........column:8    new_column_required?
----------   --------    --------   --------    --------          ---------   --------------------
agree        disagree    agree      agree       disagree          disagree    cluster1?

disagree     NaN         disagree    disagree   NaN                agree       NaN?       
.            .           .           .          .                 .           .
.            .           .           .          .                 .           .

agree        disagree    agree       agree     disagree           agree       cluster 7?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partial k-means Clustering - considering missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73602706/partial-k-means-clustering-considering-missing-data)

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** Generate Test data

Create some (almost) random test data.

```python
cols=[f'col{i}' for i in range(1,9)]
rows=100

def create_data():
  from random import random
  for i in range(0,rows):
    yield ['agree' if random() < i/rows else 'disagree' if random() < 0.95 else None for c in cols]

df=spark.createDataFrame(list(create_data()), cols)
```

**Step 2:** Transforms Strings

The `agree`/`disagree` strings cannot by handled by the `VectorAssembler` in the step 3. So the strings are transformed into numeric values. Here we treat the Null/NaN values as third category.

```python
boolean_cols=[f'{c}_bool' for c in cols]
df2 = df.selectExpr(cols + [f'if( {c} = "agree", 1.0, if( {c} = "disagree", 2.0, 3.0)) as {b}' for c, b in zip(cols,boolean_cols)])
```

Using a [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.html) would also be an option. But as there are only two different strings this might be a bit overengineered.

**Step 3:** Create a Feature Column

PySpark's K-Means implementation expects the features in a single vector column. Use a [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.html) for this task.

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
df3 = VectorAssembler(inputCols=boolean_cols, outputCol="features").transform(df2)
```

**Step 4:** Finally run the [Clustering Algorithm](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.clustering.KMeans.html)

```python
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(k=8).setSeed(1)
kmeans.setMaxIter(10)
model = kmeans.fit(df3)
predictions = model.transform(df3)
```

After removing the intermediate columns from the output we get

```python
predictions.select(cols + ['prediction']).show()
```

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|    col1|    col2|    col3|    col4|    col5|    col6|    col7|    col8|prediction|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
[...]
|disagree|   agree|disagree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         3|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|   agree|disagree|         5|
|disagree|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|disagree|   agree|         3|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|   agree|disagree|disagree|         6|
[...]
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|         7|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|   agree|   agree|         2|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|         7|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just ran the code and realized that my data also contains NaNs. Is it possible to ignore the Nans i.e. if there are NaNs in a row..the cluster should also be NaN.

Comment: I have edited the question with NaNs for your reference

Comment: @ar_mm18 it depends a bit what you want to do with these NaN values. I have added an example to the code to handle these values as third category (see step2). Depending on your requirements, you might also filter out these rows or replace the NaN values with either agree or disagree.

Comment: Thank you very much @werner. I have one more question, If I change all the NaNs to a value and after clustering change them back to NaNs by also replacing the cluster value to NaN. Doesn't that effect my clustering? I mean the clusters are calculated using the third category but now that category is changed back to NaN.

Comment: Yes, it will. It depends how you want to treat the NaN values: you could either consider them as third category or you you could simply filter out all rows that have at least one NaN value. But that's not really a technical question. The answer depends on the requirements of your use case.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any alternative for this? Because there is an already existing code in SPSS where clustering in done by setting  \MISSING = pairWISE. I am trying to convert this code to pyspark because of technical reasons. I could not find any alternative for pairWISE in pyspark. Which is nothing but doing partial k-means cluster analysis. Previously  clusters were made by using this pairWISE code and now I have no other alternative but convert it to pyspark.

Comment: For your reference: the code used in spss is-  /MISSING=pairWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(8) 
  /METHOD=CLASSIFY
  /SAVE CLUSTER
  /PRINT INITIAL

Comment: I don't think that Spark's K-Mean implementation has a similar feature like ` \MISSING = pairWISE`. But I am not familiar with SPSS. Maybe you should ask a new question how to replicate SPSS's pairWISE feature in Spark?

Comment: Thank you very much @werner. Really appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.ClusteringEvaluator

// Loads data.
val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_kmeans_data.txt")

// Trains a k-means model.
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

// Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(dataset)

// Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
val evaluator = new ClusteringEvaluator()

val silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(s"Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = $silhouette")

// Shows the result.
println("Cluster Centers: ")
model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

More info here.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

Here is the parent link.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html