# Partial k-means Clustering - considering missing data

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, k-means, spss

I have a big data frame, I have to use specific 8 columns from the data frame where the values are either "strongly agree", "agree" or "disagree". Depending on these 8 columns, I need to create a new column which tell which cluster(1-8) the row belongs to (preferably by using K-means clustering). But My data also has NaN values. I want to do the clustering considering the NaN values i.e., partial k-means clustering. *(please refer the dataset below)*

**This is because:**

There is an already existing code in SPSS where clustering in done by setting **\MISSING = PAIRWISE**. I am trying to convert this code to pyspark because of technical reasons. I could not find any alternative for pairWISE in pyspark( Which is nothing but doing partial k-means cluster analysis) Previously clusters were made by using this PAIRWISEcode and now I have no other alternative but convert it to pyspark.

PS: I am new to PySpark, Any help would be highly appreciated

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|    col1|    col2|    col3|    col4|    col5|    col6|    col7|    col8| Cluster  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|NaN     |disagree|disagree|NaN     |disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         2|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
|disagree|NaN     |disagree|disagree|NaN     |NaN     |disagree|disagree|         5|
[...]
|disagree|   agree|disagree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         3|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|         1|
|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|disagree|   agree|disagree|         5|
|disagree|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|disagree|   agree|         3|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|disagree|   agree|disagree|disagree|         6|
[...]
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|         7|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|disagree|   agree|   agree|         2|
|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|   agree|         7|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

The spss code is as follows:

```
QUICK CLUSTER 
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6
col7
col8
  /MISSING=pairWISE
  /CRITERIA=CLUSTER(8) 
  /METHOD=CLASSIFY
  /SAVE CLUSTER
  /PRINT INITIAL
  /FILE='file.sav'.

Value labels Q_Cluster 1 "Cluster 1" 2 "Cluster 2" 3 "Cluster 3" 4 "Cluster 4"
    5 "Cluster 5" 6 "Cluster 6" 7 "Cluster 7" 8 "Cluster 8".
Execute.

*Exclusion of cases with too high a number (>4) of missing values in the cluster-forming variables; name of the cluster variables behind 'Recode' may have to be adjusted.
COUNT Miscount=col1 col2 col3
    col4 col5 col6 col7
    col8(SYSMIS).
VARIABLE LABELS  Miscount 'Number of missings in cluster image. Var.'.
DO IF (Miscount>4).
RECODE Q_Cluster (1 thru 8=SYSMIS).
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Any ideas on how to exclude the NaN cases would be really helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [K-Means Clustering in Py-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618693/k-means-clustering-in-py-spark)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, K-means clustering in Pyspark doesn't support so-called "partial clustering", i.e., every row in every column should be a quantitive value. Therefore I believe you have to modify the spark code to achieve the same goal in SPSS.

Actually, this will trigger another question. Based on my understanding, K-means clustering uses Euclidean distance to calculate, which means all values in each row should be a quantitive value. Based on the example dataframe that you provided, how do you want to OR how does SPSS handle the null value imputation? Do you have any references or papers so that we can transfer the methodology by using pyspark?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will this reference help? Pairwise deletion occurs when the statistical procedure uses cases that contain some missing data. The procedure cannot include a particular variable when it has a missing value, but it can still use the case when analyzing other variables with non-missing values. A case may contain 3 variables: VAR1, VAR2, and VAR3. A case may have a missing value for VAR1, but this does not prevent some statistical procedures from using the same case to analyze variables VAR2 and VAR3. Pairwise deletion allows you to use more of your data.

Comment: However, each computed statistic may be based on a different subset of cases. This can be problematic. For example, a correlation matrix computed using pairwise deletion may not be positive semidefinite. That is, it may have negative eigenvalues, which can create problems for various statistical analyses. This can occur because when correlations are computed using different cases, the resulting patterns can be ones that are impossible to produce with complete data.