# K-Means Clustering in Py-spark

Tags: pyspark, k-means

I have a really big data frame. I am considering 8 columns to make 8 clusters. Now, normally the code would discard a row even if 1 of the 8 column values is NaN. In my case, I have to write a pyspark code that behaves in such a way that(Even When a row has some NaN values, the code will ignore them and take other column values into consideration and thereby performing clustering even for rows that have some NaN values)Any help or lead is highly appreciated. [image: Data_Set_Example]

Comment: what if you replace the NaN with 'other' value and then do clustering?

Comment: @samkart unfortunately replacing the NaN with a number is not a solution in my case. Previously my team did the same type of clustering as mentioned in my question which is possible in a tool SPSS. Now I have to do the same in PySpark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [K means Clustering using PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73592447/k-means-clustering-using-pyspark)

Comment: @JonathanLam The one you suggested was also asked by me. That does not have this NaN condition in it. So It is not help ful unfortunately